# Data structure for a rolling history of position

Tags: delphi, data-structures

I have a application reading in offset values from external data source. These offsets are +- from the centrepoint (nom =0).

I would like to save the last minute of these offsets and display them on a scrolling graph. This graph needs to automatically adjust its min/max values according to the data over the last minute.

So i can see this is pointing toward a FIFO queue.

I am using Delphi 7, however when trying to use the TQueue class i cant see any way of accessing a value in the queue (rather only the top of the queue) using Peek().

Is there a better data structure for my problem?

I need to store 60 floating point numbers, access all of them to display on the graph and determine the maximum value in the queue at any point in time.

Comment: An array should do, if delphi has it...

Comment: I would rather not have to re-allocate values in an array when a new one is pushed into the array. i know 60 is not many, but on the future this could expand.

Comment: Like Josh said a circular buffer will do, which can be implemented as an array. Just have an extra window_start variable. A new element, you add at window_start and increment window_start modulo 60.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat:  I don't know Delphi.  But in language agnostic terms, you can just maintain some kind of circular buffer with the appropriate size.  Back it with an array and have your write pointer cycle through the array indices.  Your reads start from write pointer if the buffer is filled, else 0 if it is not.

For finding min/max, there are several things you can do:

1. The naive approach: recompute min and max every time.  O(n).  (Not too bad for n=60.)
2. Slightly better: only recompute min and max when the min or max is popped.  (Of course you need to update it for every push too.)  O(n).
3. Asymptotically good: keep your values in a self-balancing binary search tree.  Insert into the tree when you push onto the circular buffer and delete from the tree when you pop from the buffer.  O(log n).

Comment: You forgot to mention heap :-) +1 though.

Comment: @Moron, yes a heap works, but then you need two (one for min, one for max).  Maybe worth doing if you have a heap handy but not a tree.